# Get aggregated query result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: tbl_recipe and tbl_directions. Each "direction" has a foreign key, which is recipe's primary key.

At the end of the day, I want to be able to show a json result that looks like the following (other props omitted for brevity):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sandwich",
    ...
    "directions": {
      [
        {
          ...
          "recipe_id": 1,
          "directions": "Get bread"
        },
        {
          ...
          "recipe_id": 1,
          "directions": "Spread"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Fried Eggs",
    ...
    "directions": {
      [
        {
          ...
          "recipe_id": 2,
          "directions": "Heat pan"
        },
        {
          ...
          "recipe_id": 2,
          "directions": "Crack eggs"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

One thing I can think of is doing "select * from tbl_recipe", then loop through results and query for directions of each result. I'm almost positive that there has got to be a better/proper way of doing this.

***tbl_recipe***

id: 1, name: Sandwich
id: 2, name: Fried eggs

***tbl_directions***

id:1, recipe_id:1, directions: Get bread
id:2, recipe_id:1, directions: Spread

id:3, recipe_id:2, directions: Heat pan
id:4, recipe_id:2, directions: Break eggs

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want a [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG. A join did cross my mind, but then I will end up with multiple duplicate recipe rows. Should I just do some post-processing on that result set?

Comment: You need to, as briefly as possible, provide example table data and what you want the result to look like. That way we can suggest a suitable JOIN query. SQL is pretty powerful; the goal is usually to write a query in such a way that post-processing is not necessary.

Comment: I edited the post to show some sample data. As for the result, I already included it as the sample json result when I first posted. Thanks!

Comment: The basic idea is this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f4c3c/6

Comment: Thanks again @ChrisG. Yeah, that's what I meant by duplicate recipe rows. I think post-processing is the only way to go at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to query the result with a left join and do post processing on the result of duplicate rows like you mentioned.

`select * from recipe r left join directions d on r.id = d.recipe_id`

After executing the query and fetching the result in the post processing, try to maintain a map of recipe Vs list of directions like Map and add the direction corresponding to a recipe to the list

Also i would as well advise you to take a look at document datastores like MongoDB as your dataset seems very much closer to the use cases of a document store

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @aarish. This is likely one way to go, but ChrisG from the comment above is saying that there might be a way to avoid post processing, and let SQL do most of the work. What do you think?